# How can we check if the set is path-connected?

Tags: general-topology, analysis, connectedness, path-connected

I want to check if the following sets is connected, and path-connected.

A set can be path-connected only if it is connected, or not?

$$\displaystyle{A=\{x\in \mathbb{R}^2 : 1\leq x_1^2+x_2^2\leq 4\}}$$

Let $f: [1, 2]\times[0, 2\pi] \to A$ with $f(r, \theta) = (r\cos\theta, r\sin\theta)$.

The function $f$ is continuous and $[1, 2]\times[0, 2\pi]$ is connected. So the image $A$ is also connected.

How can we check if this is set is path-connected?

Comment: Hint: if you have a continuous surjection from a path-connected space onto another space, then the other space is also path-connected. Can you see why?

Comment: Ah I see!! Thank you!! :-) @MeesdeVries

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Mees de Vries hinted above, all you have to do is note that $[1, 2] \times [0, 2\pi] \subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ (where $\mathbb{R}^2$ has the usual topology on it) is path-connected.

And analogously to the theorem that the continuous image of a connected space is connected, there's a theorem that states the continuous image of a path-connected space is path-connected.

So since $f$ is continuous we have $f\left[[1, 2] \times [0, 2\pi]\right] = A$ to be path-connected by the above theorem.

Comment: Is every subsace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ path-connected?

Comment: @MaryStar No, take for example $A = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | x \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{and } \ y > 0\}$ and $B = \{(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 \ | x \in \mathbb{R} \ \text{and } \ y < 0\}$, then $A \cup B$ is a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ which isn't path-connected. I only mentioned the topology on $\mathbb{R}^2$ because if we had the discrete topology on it then $[1, 2] \times [0, 2\pi]$ considered as a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with the discrete topology would not be connected.

Comment: I understand!! Thank you!! :-)

Comment: @MaryStar No problem, I could prove that $[1, 2] \times [0, 2\pi]$ is path connected explicitly if you'd like

Comment: Shall I tell you how I thought that we can prove that?  $$$$ $[1, 2]$ is path-connected:
Let $x,y\in [1, 2]$. The function $g:[0,1]\rightarrow [1, 2]$ with $g(t) = tx + (1-t)y$ describes a path from $y$ to $x$ with $x,y\in [1, 2]$.  
$$$$ In the same way we show also that $[0, 2\pi]$  is path-connected. 

$$$$ Then the product of path-connected spaces is again path-connected, or not?

Comment: @MaryStar Yep that looks good to me, the product of path-connected spaces is path-connected

Comment: Great!! Thanks a lot!!